# Nearly regex with glob

Tags: php, regex, glob

PHP's `glob` seems to support a [limited-range of regex-like syntax](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.glob.php#88250).

I would like to catch `hello<somethingherebutonlyifitbeginsby#>.txt`, i.e.:

- hello.txt: ok
- hello#you.txt: ok
- hellome.txt: not ok

I tried

```
glob('hello#?*.txt', GLOB_BRACE);
```

but it doesn't work. How can we correct it?

Comment: `glob` doesn't support regex. It supports standard command line wildcards. For example, `.*` doesn't mean any number of any character (regex), it means a literal dot followed by anything.

Comment: So does this mean it's impossible with `glob`?

Comment: It would be easier to just lookup `hello*.txt` and then filter out the ones you don't want. That or two different globs, one for `hello.txt` and one for `hello#*.txt`. With the prior being more performant. I guess a search for `hello#*.txt` and then just checking if `hello.txt` exists would be another option that is quick.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Niiiiiice for the second method! How to join `glob('*hello.txt') + glob('*hello#*.txt')` ?

Comment: array_merge. A union (using addition on the arrays) won't append numeric keys like array_merge would. I would just do array_merge and array_unique to filter out duplicates.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I would accept this answer, thanks one million times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it like that:

```
glob('hello{#*,}.txt', GLOB_BRACE);
```

where `{aa,bb}` is an alternation (feature available with the `GLOB_BRACE` and with OSes that support it).

Comment: Wonderful! Already [committed here](https://github.com/josephernest/bloggggg/commit/727c1d807b682b4c37e10a574056319d712a48f2), see https://github.com/josephernest/bloggggg

Answer (score 0):

> glob's regex also supports character classes and negative character classes, using the syntax [] and [^]. It will match any one character inside [] or match any one character that is not in [^].
>
> ```
> hello.txt: ok
> hello#you.txt: ok
> hellome.txt: not ok
> ```

```
//[] include chars. and #
var_dump(glob('hello[.#]*txt', GLOB_BRACE));

array(2) {
[0]=>
 string(13) "hello#you.txt"
[1]=>
 string(9) "hello.txt"
}


>ls hello* 
hellome.txt  hello.txt  hello#you.txt
```